# Must declare the scalar variable of cursor in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have this procedure in SQL Server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[QC_data_integrity]  
AS
    DECLARE @SQLScript VarChar(MAX)
    DECLARE @TableName3 VarChar(MAX)
    DECLARE @Starttime as datetime
    
    DECLARE @column_name VarChar(MAX)
    DECLARE @data_type VarChar(MAX)
    
    DECLARE @sqldatabase VarChar(MAX)
    DECLARE @tbllookup VarChar(MAX)
    DECLARE @sqlserver VarChar(MAX)
    
    SET @Starttime = GETDATE()
            
    DECLARE @Tblname VarChar(MAX)
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
    
BEGIN
    
    DECLARE cur_lookup CURSOR FOR
        SELECT * 
        FROM Abc.dbo.Abc_lookup_tables 
        WHERE tablename = 'APFH104'
    
    OPEN cur_lookup;
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur_lookup INTO @sqldatabase, @tbllookup, @sqlserver;

    WHILE @@Fetch_status = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL=' use '+@sqldatabase+'
    
        SET @Tblname = ''['+ @sqldatabase +']' + '.dbo.' +'['+ @tbllookup+']''

        DECLARE cur_tracking CURSOR FOR
            SELECT column_name, data_type 
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
            WHERE TABLE_NAME = ' + @tbllookup +
            ' ORDER BY ordinal_position
    
        OPEN cur_tracking;

        FETCH NEXT FROM cur_tracking INTO @column_name, @data_type;

        WHILE @@Fetch_status = 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT @column_name 
            FROM @Tblname
    
            FETCH NEXT FROM cur_tracking INTO @column_name, @data_type;
        END;

        CLOSE cur_tracking;
        DEALLOCATE cur_tracking;'

        EXEC sp_executesql @sql

        FETCH NEXT FROM cur_lookup INTO @sqldatabase, @tbllookup, @sqlserver;
    END;

    CLOSE cur_lookup;
    DEALLOCATE cur_lookup;
END
```

I basically need `"USE database"` statement because this `"INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS"` only works while using `"USE database"`

So,`"use database"` is not allowed without keeping inside the quote in procedure since it throws error so I kept in quote `set @SQL=''`and tried to execute using `Exec sp_executesql @sql` but
I am getting errors:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 68
> Must declare the scalar variable "@Tblname".
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 73
> Must declare the scalar variable "@column_name".
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 77
> Must declare the scalar variable "@column_name".
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 79
> Must declare the scalar variable "@column_name".

I needed all the `columns name` from each table so I needed to use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and need to print all column names of each table. So, I tried using this way.

Comment: YOu aren't passing your variables/parameters to your dynamic statement, so they have no context in said dynamic statement. You also have `SET @TableName3 = @TableName`, however, `@TableName` hasn't been defined prior to that statement.

Comment: I must admit, though, this looks/smells of an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info). What are you trying to achieve wit the above?

Comment: Also `'['+ @tbllookup+']'` is **not** injection safe. Object names can (and some foolishly do) contain the character `]`. If you need to inject an object name validate it (where possible) and use `QUOTENAME` to safely escape the value.

Comment: @larnu tablename3 is not being used. Sorry that i needed to remove it.

Comment: the variable @column_name is not being read from cursor. Why is it happening? since my cursor are inside quotes, is it fine?

Comment: Aside... database, object and column names are typically of the `SYSNAME` data type, which is a synonym for `NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL`. i.e.: you should be using `nvarchar` data types so that you can handle non-ASCII characters and you should be sizing them appropriately. `(max)` is not appropriate.

Comment: @larnu i changed it into `set @Tblname = '+ @sqldatabase +'.dbo.'+@tbllookup+';` but still the same error

Comment: That's even worse, @AshwinKarki ... *"If you need to inject an object name validate it (where possible) and use `QUOTENAME` to safely escape the value."*

Comment: `sp_executesql` executes the code in a new scope. You either need to declare those scalar variables inside that scope, or [pass them in as parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql#b-executing-a-dynamically-built-string).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning i corrected all the changes thank you

Comment: This absolutely does not need a cursor, certainly not two of them You could just build one big SQL string using `STRING_AGG` and `QUOTENAME`, with three part naming `database.schema.table`, then execute the whole thing in one go.